# Components of सर्वस्याऽपि

Tags: sanskrit, sandhi

I am trying to study Sanskrit. I am right now reading the following article on [Shivaji](https://sa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF_%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%80) in Sanskrit. There is a sentence `सर्वस्याऽपि दोषिणः योग्यं दण्डं विदधाति।` I get what it means, roughly that every violator is given the right kind of punishment. However, I want to analyse each word. The term `सर्वस्याऽपि` has stymied me. I don't know how to split it. Can anybody help me split it?

Comment: You should consider the possibility that this is an error. Avagraha for /a/ of /api/ arises after /e,o/. /sarvasya + api/ would give सर्वस्यापि.

Comment: @user6726 Yes of course

Comment: Some publications do (graphically) indicate the merging of two a-vowels by an *avagraha*, for which there are no hard-and-fast rules (known to me), when to do it and I am pretty sure, that there aren't. In my edition of the *Patanjali-Yogasutras* (which at the moment I couldn't find online any more but have printed with me), it says in verse 5: ...क्लिष्टाऽक्लिष्टाः, which is essentially the same type of sandhi as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The avagraha ऽ is used to denote सन्धिः between two vowels. As @zwiebel noted, this convention is not strictly followed in print. 
For e.g 
`रामस्य अलङ्कारः` can be written in two different ways:

`रामस्यालङ्कारः` - sandhi without ऽ

`रामस्याऽलङ्कारः` - the single ऽ denotes that a short अ has been replaced with आ due to सन्धिः

`रामस्य आलयः`

`रामालयः` = सन्धिः sandhi without ऽ

`रामाऽऽलयः` - सन्धिः the two ऽऽ denote that आ in the latter word has been replaced due to सन्धिः